# Delphi TAdoDataset TFloatField comma error

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-2007

My platform Delphi 2007 and SQL Server 2008 R2
When I post my `TAdoDataset`, I receiving this code at Sql profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE "MYDBNAME"."dbo"."HESAPISL" SET "ADET"=@P1,"FIYAT"=@P2,"TARIFEID"=@P3,"KRMTUTAR"=@P4,"SGTUTAR"=@P5,"OZELTUTAR"=@P6,"HSTKATKITUTAR"=@P7,"KRMINDORAN"=@P8,"KRMINDTUTAR"=@P9,"OZELINDORAN"=@P10,"OZELINDTUTAR"=@P11,"SGINDORAN"=@P12,"HIKUTUICIADET"=@P13,"HSTKDVORAN"=@P14,"KRMKDVORAN"=@P15,"SGKDVORAN"=@P16,"EKMASRAFTUTAR"=@P17,"HSTPAKETDURUMUID"=@P18,"KRMPAKETDURUMUID"=@P19,"SGPAKETDURUMUID"=@P20,"HSTPAKETEDAHIL"=@P21,"KRMPAKETEDAHIL"=@P22,"SGPAKETEDAHIL"=@P23,"ESKIITEMID"=@P24,"ESKIADET"=@P25,"ESKIHIKUTUICIADET"=@P26,"HSTFYTTUTAR"=@P27,"HKMATRAH"=@P28,"MLYTTUTAR"=@P29,"BAZFYTBIRIM"=@P30 
WHERE "ADET"=@P31 AND "FIYAT"=@P32 AND "TARIFEID"=@P33 AND "KRMTUTAR"=@P34 AND "SGTUTAR"=@P35 AND "OZELTUTAR"=@P36 AND "HSTKATKITUTAR"=@P37 AND "KRMINDORAN"=@P38 AND "KRMINDTUTAR"=@P39 AND "OZELINDORAN"=@P40 AND "OZELINDTUTAR"=@P41 AND "SGINDORAN"=@P42 AND "HIKUTUICIADET"=@P43 AND "HSTKDVORAN"=@P44 AND "KRMKDVORAN"=@P45 AND "SGKDVORAN"=@P46 AND "EKMASRAFTUTAR"=@P47 AND "HSTPAKETDURUMUID"=@P48 AND "KRMPAKETDURUMUID"=@P49 AND "SGPAKETDURUMUID"=@P50 AND "HSTPAKETEDAHIL"=@P51 AND "KRMPAKETEDAHIL"=@P52 AND "SGPAKETEDAHIL"=@P53 AND "ESKIITEMID" IS NULL AND "ESKIADET" IS NULL AND "ESKIHIKUTUICIADET" IS NULL AND "HSTFYTTUTAR"=@P54 AND "HKMATRAH"=@P55 AND "MLYTTUTAR"=@P56 AND "BAZFYTBIRIM"=@P57 AND "HESAPISLID"=@P58 AND "HESAPISLID" IS NULL',N'@P1 float,@P2 float,@P3 int,@P4 float,@P5 float,@P6 float,@P7 float,@P8 float,@P9 float,@P10 float,@P11 float,@P12 float,@P13 numeric(9,2),@P14 numeric(5,2),@P15 numeric(5,2),@P16 numeric(5,2),@P17 float,@P18 int,@P19 int,@P20 int,@P21 bit,@P22 bit,@P23 bit,@P24 int,@P25 float,@P26 numeric(8,2),@P27 float,@P28 float,@P29 float,@P30 numeric(19,4),@P31 float,@P32 float,@P33 int,@P34 float,@P35 float,@P36 float,@P37 float,@P38 float,@P39 float,@P40 float,@P41 float,@P42 float,@P43 numeric(9,2),@P44 numeric(5,2),@P45 numeric(5,2),@P46 numeric(5,2),@P47 float,@P48 int,@P49 int,@P50 int,@P51 bit,@P52 bit,@P53 bit,@P54 float,@P55 float,@P56 float,@P57 numeric(19,4),@P58 int',4,0,078299999999999995,4,0,0,0,31319999999999998,0,0,0,0,0,0,30.00,8.00,8.00,8.00,0,00013333333333337416,0,0,0,0,0,0,7516,6,30.00,0,31333333333333335,0,0,0,6,0,078299999999999995,4,0,0,0,4698,0,0,0,0,0,0,30.00,8.00,8.00,0,0,00020000000000003348,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,47000000000000003,0,0,2.3500,53791
```

---

Example:

`HSTKDVORAN = 8.00` (This is OK! no problem)

But

`FIYAT = 0,078299999999999995` (this is causing an exception/problem)

Float fields values are coming with comma seperated.

When I run this code (at SQL Management Studio), it gets an error:

```
Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
Procedure or function has too many arguments specified.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

if FIYAT = 0,078299999999999995 then the procedure have one more Value (0 and 078299999999999995)
FIYAT must be 0.078299999999999995

You can use the TAdoDataSet or TAdoCommand
set property CommandType: cmdStoredProc and select the store procedure from property Commandtext.
From property Parameters you can see all the arguments of the store procedure.

```
<TADODataSet>.Parameters.ParamByName('@FIYAT').Value:=0.078299999999999995;
<TADODataSet>.Parameters.ParamByName('@FIYAT').Value:='0,078299999999999995';  --> not ok
```

Value is Variant. You must specify you argument

If you use TAdoDataset to link the table MYDBNAME.dbo.HESAPISL

```
property CommandType: cmdText
property CommandText: 'select HSTKDVORAN, FIYAT from MYDBNAME.dbo.HESAPISL';

<TAdoDataset>.FieldByName('FIYAT').AsFloat:= 0.078299999999999995;
```

Code from the comment

```
 tHILACMALZ1ADET.Value := tHILACMALZADET.AsFloat; 
 tHILACMALZ1HIKUTUICIADET.Value := FDM.tITEMKUTUICIADET.AsFloat; 
 tHILACMALZ1.Post;
```

change in

```
 tHILACMALZ1ADET.AsFloat:= tHILACMALZADET.AsFloat; 
 tHILACMALZ1HIKUTUICIADET.AsFloat:= FDM.tITEMKUTUICIADET.AsFloat; 
 tHILACMALZ1.Post;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
After this change i tested it. After 'tHILACMALZ1.Post',  i looked at SQL Profiler. Commas still generated for TFloatField's values.
BCD fields values are ​​separated by dots, but floatfield's values are comma-separated in same auto-generated SQL command. And it's causing error.

Comment: is tHILACMALZ1HIKUTUICIADET a float type or is the field of tHILACMALZ1HIKUTUICIADET = TFloatField

Comment: Description of SQL Server: HIKUTUICIADET Float (not Null) and
Object Inspector: TFloatField

Comment: I'm using view with my adodataset. It has a lot of table joins.
Our department's manager, said to me: Remove only one "dbo." for one table. He said: "That's a bug of Ado". Really i don't understand it but it works. All table and field definitions have a "dbo." prefix but only one Table haven't got it. When i remove "dbo." before it. It's working!

Thank you for everything..

Comment: There is a part of my view code:
...
 dbo.HKIMLIK INNER JOIN
 dbo.HDOSYA ON dbo.HKIMLIK.HKIMLIKID = dbo.HDOSYA.HKIMLIKID INNER JOIN
 HESAPISL INNER JOIN
 dbo.HMALZILAC ON dbo.HESAPISL.HESAPISLID = dbo.HMALZILAC.HESAPISLID ON dbo.HDOSYA.HDOSYAID =  dbo.HMALZILAC.HDOSYAID ON 
 dbo.TITEM.ITEMID = dbo.HESAPISL.ITEMID LEFT OUTER JOIN
...
Only "HESAPISL" don't have a "dbo." prefix! (at the middle of code above) That's all it.